# Query does not return all rows every time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

We have two simple queries (inside stored procedure, used by website) as:

```
    if @a = 1
begin
select a.col1, a.col2 , b.col1 from table1 a join table2 b
on a.id = b.id 
where a.col1 = 'yyyy'
end
else
begin
select a.col1, a.col2 , b.col1 from table1 a join table2 b
on a.id = b.id 
where a.col1 = 'zzzz'
end
```

There is never problem with first query (@a = 1). Second one is supposed to return 48 rows (tables are not written often). Ones or twice per day (out of hundreds hits) second query returns 10 or 30 rows (To debug i inserted @@rowcount into another table). So to force it to return me 48 rows I tried something like this:

```
else
again:
begin
select a.col1, a.col2 , b.col1 from table1 a join table2 b
on a.id = b.id 
where a.col1 = 'zzzz'
if @@rowcount <> 48 goto again
end
```

,
it keeps looping for minutes (never returns 48 rows) until i kill the spid.

Any idea would help.
Thanks

Comment: maybe you don't have 48 rows?

Comment: If the query one does not return 48 rows the first time why do you think it would do that the second time?

Comment: I hope it would return 48 rows second time - in case there was lock issue or something , which does not make sense if there was a lock it would not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning 10 or 30, the combination will never be 48.

change it to:

```
if @@rowcount >= 48 goto again
```

even though, I believe your work around doesnt make much sense.
Do you really have 48 rows on your second select?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. Second query always should return 48 rows (like it does 99% of time). So if it return less than 48 I would like it to run again (that is why i am checking @@rowcount).